# How to fix inputting the user's info twice?

Tags: java

The program ask for a month and it could be a string or int. In the isDigitsOrSpecial method, it works and it has the same format in my method isString. The difference is that when I want to enter the month in a string way (ex.january), it will ask me twice. So, I don't know what to do. I tried a lot of ways but it doesn't work. Do you have any suggestions?

Here's my full code. You can try to run it, and see the problem where you have to input twice the name of the month in a string way.

I would really appreciate any of your suggestions.

```java
package Electronic_payment_process;

import java.util.InputMismatchException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class practice {

    static String s;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        float current = 0, recent = 0, difference, multiply;

        String month, recents, currents = null;

        System.out.println("The month could be a number or a name.");
        System.out.println("Example: (01-12) or (JAN – dec)");

        // for the validation of due month user’s input
        do {
            System.out.print("\nEnter a month: ");
            month = scan.next();
            if (isDigitsOrSpecial(month)) {
                System.out.print("proceed");
                break;
            } else if (isString(month)) {
                System.out.print("proceed");
                break;
            }
        } while (true);

        // for the validation of current meter reading
        do {
            System.out.print("\nEnter current reading: ");
            try {
                current = scan.nextFloat();

                System.out.println("proceed");
                currents = String.format("%.2f", current);
                if (current <= 0) {
                    System.out.println("Invalid input");
                }
            } catch (InputMismatchException a) {
                System.out.println("Must enter a number");
                scan.next();
            }
        } while (current <= 0);

        // for the validation of recent meter reading
        do {
            System.out.print("Enter recent reading: ");
            try {
                recent = scan.nextFloat();
                if (recent < current) {
                    System.out.println("proceed");
                    recents = String.format("%.2f", recent);
                    break;
                } else {
                    System.out.println("recent must be less than current");
                }
            } catch (InputMismatchException a) {
                System.out.println("Must enter a number");
                scan.next();
            }
        } while (true);

        difference = current - recent;
        multiply = difference * 50;

        System.out.println("====================================================================================");
        System.out.println("MONTH    " + "   RECENT    " + "CURRENT    " + "TOTAL USAGE    " + "Price per unit    " + "TOTAL AMOUNT    ");
        System.out.println((s + ("    ") + recents + (" kW") + ("  ") + currents + (" kW") + ("       ") + difference + ("        ") + ("50php") + ("           ") + multiply));
    }

    public static boolean isDigitsOrSpecial(String month) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        if (month != null) {
            for (char ch : month.toCharArray()) {
                if (Character.isLetter(ch)) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
        int we = Integer.parseInt(month);
        s = Integer.toString(we);
        if (null == month) {
            s = scan.nextLine();
        } else switch (we) {
            case 01:
                s = "January";
                break;
            case 02:
                s = "February";
                break;
            case 03:
                s = "March";
                break;
            case 04:
                s = "April";
                break;
            case 05:
                s = "May";
                break;
            case 06:
                s = "June";
                break;
            case 07:
                s = "July";
                break;
            case 8:
                s = "August";
                break;
            case 9:
                s = "September";
                break;
            case 10:
                s = "October";
                break;
            case 11:
                s = "November";
                break;
            case 12:
                s = "December";
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("You have entered an invalid number of month");
        }
        return true;
    }

    public static boolean isString(String month) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        if (null != month) {
            char[] chars = month.toCharArray();
            s = scan.nextLine();
            for (char c : chars) {
                if (!Character.isLetter(c)) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
        if (!(month.length() >= 3)) {
            System.out.println("Name of month must be at least 3 letters.Please try again");
            return false;
        } else if (month.startsWith("jan") || month.startsWith("JAN") || month.startsWith("Jan")) {
            s = "January";
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Instead of your multiple startsWith() tests, just use ``month.toLowerCase().startsWith("jan")``

Comment: NomadMaker thankss, I will do that :)

Answer (score 1):

I see we have added additional scanner statements inside isDigit or isString methods. I have removed them and it looks good to me.

```
public static boolean isDigitsOrSpecial(String month) {
        if (month != null) {
            for (char ch : month.toCharArray()) {
                if (Character.isLetter(ch)) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
        int we = Integer.parseInt(month);
        switch (we) {
        case 01:
            s = "January";
            break;
        case 02:
            s = "February";
            break;
        case 03:
            s = "March";
            break;
        case 04:
            s = "April";
            break;
        case 05:
            s = "May";
            break;
        case 06:
            s = "June";
            break;
        case 07:
            s = "July";
            break;
        case 8:
            s = "August";
            break;
        case 9:
            s = "September";
            break;
        case 10:
            s = "October";
            break;
        case 11:
            s = "November";
            break;
        case 12:
            s = "December";
            break;
        default:
            System.out.println("You have entered an invalid number of month");
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    public static boolean isString(String month)

    {
        if (null != month) {
            char[] chars = month.toCharArray();
            for (char c : chars) {
                if (!Character.isLetter(c)) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }

        if (!(month.length() >= 3)) {

            System.out.println("Name of month must be at least 3 letters.Please try again");
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: Vinayagam R but how can I call the variable 's'? I needed that for the final output (it's the last println in thr main method).

Comment: If I put the s in the main, then the other method can't access them